# How to get ID's with complete set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have following table:

```
UserId      UserDb      Systolic    Diastolic   Weight      Height
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1000022     2           0           0           0           67
1000022     2           23          323         33          0
50508       30          3           3           33          39
51604       0           0           44          44          191
51318       0           0           0           0           0
```

How I can get UserId's with complete set of records? I mean that data can be scattered between records, like user with **1000022** id have *height* record in one row, and *weight*, *systolic* and *diastolic* in other rows.

I have the solution with table variables but it isn't efficient and flexible. Is it possible to make such kind of query?

I would like to get that ID's:

```
UserId
-----------
1000022
50508
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  userID
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY UserID
HAVING  MAX(UserDb) <> 0 AND
        MAX(Systolic) <> 0 AND
        MAX(Diastolic) <> 0 AND   
        MAX(Weight) <> 0 AND
        MAX(Height) <> 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1a3d/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╗
║ USERID  ║
╠═════════╣
║   50508 ║
║ 1000022 ║
╚═════════╝
```